# Calling a Java 8 function only once when iterating a function list

Tags: java, function, lambda, java-8

Is there an elegant way to store the return value of the `apply()` method so it won't have to be invoked more than once? Because the only way I could think of is to create a local map variable that will store the function-"return value" pairs.

```
@Autowired
private List<Function<String, String>> evaluators; 
//...
private String evaluate(String code) {  
    return evaluators.stream().filter(f -> f.apply(code) != null).findFirst().get().apply(code); 
}
```

Comment: But if you invoke the method with different `code`, you'd expect different result, right? So you want a cache of the code to result of applying the function?

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a caching mechanism already built-in on Java 8.

Comment: Nothing built in. The concept is called "memoization" so try to google for that. The general approach would be a method that wraps your lambda instance with a memoizing layer.

Comment: Look here for a memoizer class https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-automatic-memoization

Comment: @Joop Eggen: a typical case of over-lambdaification, using `function::apply` to convert a `Function` to a `Function`. Besides that, the “benchmark” in that article is ridiculous.

Comment: @Holger to their justification that was no benchmark. And wrapping a caching function around another, so they can be  replaced like in the case of the OP's list of functions is at least theoretical sound. Efficiency is another case. But I can share your sentiments, though get me going mention the forced "three corners turning left" usage of Streams.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: it was not called benchmark, but measuring the subsequent execution time of the same function in a JVM will almost always produce a shorter execution time for the second execution, memoization or not. So measuring and printing these times has no point.

Comment: @Holger lying benchmarks & statistics; thanks.

Comment: @Holger is right. I thought caching was the only way to remove the second call to `apply()` function, so I mistakenly introduced it as a solution. But anyway, thanks @Marko Topolnik and @Joop Eggen for mentioning memoization. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
  private String evaluate(String code) {  
      return evaluators.stream()
          .map(f -> f.apply(code))
          .filter(s -> s != null)
          .findFirst().get();
  }
```

Comment: Wait, was this the question? I thought OP wanted [to cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038340/calling-a-java-8-function-only-once-when-iterating-a-function-list#comment67352825_40038340) the result of applying a function to a given code? This will still invoke the functions if you call `evaluate` with the same code.

Comment: @Tunaki: this answer identified the xy-problem of the question. The original stream code unnecessarily invokes the same function twice. Fixing that problem removes the need for caching results.

Comment: @saka1029: the tests showed a non-greedy fashion on invoking the functions in the `evaluators` list. Fantastic! :)